# Associativity of upvalue

Tags: operators

how can I ensure the following definition to be associative?

```
Unprotect[Times];
a_ f[x_] + b_ f[y_] ^:= f[a x + b y]
Protect[Times];
```

gives me

```
a f[x] + b f[y] + c f[z]
```

> f[a x + b y] + c f[z]

I'd like it to be

> f[a x + b y + c z]

Comment: You probably need to set default values for the patterns `a_` and `b_` like `a_.` and `b_.`, otherwise `\[ScriptCapitalN][a x + b y]` does not match the pattern of `multiplier_ \[ScriptCapitalN][a x + b y]`

Comment: My previous comment about `Times` vs. `Plus` was of course wrong.

Comment: Well it works with the default value. But I don't really understand why I need it.

Comment: And if c=1 it does not work anymore.

Comment: See my answer for a better way.

Comment: Just something that caught my eye: Wouldn't it be more pleasing to replace `\[ScriptCapitalN]` by a more-legible symbol, say `f` when posting here? ;)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher it would be even better if the tools for substituting stuff like `\[Alpha]` also worked for `\[ScriptCapitalN]` ;-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That's easy to achieve. Just go to thw NinjaKot script and add `['\\\\\\[ScriptCapitalN\\]', 'f'],` on line 599 =D

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher these double escapes are hurting my eyes :)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the inconvenience :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f[a x + b y] + c f[z]
```

is *not* the same as

```
1 * f[a x + b y] + c f[z]
```

so the pattern

```
a_ f[x] + b_ f[y]
```

does not match it. But if you use `a_.` then it's replaced with the default value (1, for `Times`) if the multiplier is omitted. So then it will match.

However, you observe that if `c == 1`, then it doesn't work again. This is understandable, since if `c == 1`, the expression

```
f[a x + b y] + f[z]
```

does not contain `Times` at level 1 anymore. I suggest using more granular rules:

```
a_ f[x_] ^:= f[a x]

f[x_] + f[y_] ^:= f[x + y]
```

This achieves two things: the upvalue is attached to `f` and not to system symbols, and it solves the problem you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But isn't the case `c==1` a variant of the first case, now with the two multipliers omitted? And shouldn't then the two multipliers be replaced with their default values? Or did I get it completely wrong what you tried to point out? [Edit] Or can only be one default value be replaced at a time?

Comment: The `UpValue` in your attempt is associated with `Times`. I replace scriptcapitalN with just `N` for brevity: `N[x] + b N[y]` is `Plus[N[x], Times[b, N[y]]]`. `Times` is present at level 1 of the expression, so MMA checks `UpValues` for the symbol `Times`. However, `N[x] + N[y]` is `Plus[N[x], N[y]]`, so MMA has no waying of realizing that it has to apply the `UpValue` defined for `Times`. So it doesn't even get round to doing that and attempting to substitute default values in the process.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfectly sense.